# How to find the days b/w two long date values

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two long dates value.

```
For Ex:  1433097000000 1434479400000
```

Here i have to find the days between these two by jquery

For Ex: 15/06/2015 - 22/06/2015
If it is more than 5 days, I want to get from is 15/06/2016,  to is 19/06/2015.

It is based on long values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get your timestamps in to `Date()` objects, which is simple using the constructor. Then you can use the below function to calculate the difference in days:

```js
var date1 = new Date(1433097000000);
var date2 = new Date(1434479400000);

function daydiff(first, second) {
  return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

alert(daydiff(date1, date2));
```

Comment: I have edited my ques. If it is more than 5 days. I need to calculate the date of 5th day from starting date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d1= new Date(1433097000000);
var d2= new Date(1434479400000);

 var x = (((d2- d1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

if(x>5)
{
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 4);
    alert(d1);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzu5yjwa/3/)**

If you want to format the date in dd/mm/yyyy format you can try like this:

```
function formatdate(mydate) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(mydate);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzu5yjwa/9/)**

Comment: I have edited my ques. If it is more than 5 days. I need to calculate the date of 5th day from starting date

Comment: @Mohaideen:- Updated my answer. Please check now!